# How to configure WSO2 API Manager Analytics

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm new to `WSO2`, and I'm trying to configure a single node `WSO2 API Manager` with `Analytics` using `mysql` as the `RDBMS` on my local machine (ubuntu).

I've successfully configured the `API Manager` to use `mysql` as the `RDBMS` using the official documentation page [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-mysql/), however I can't configure the `Analytics` to use `mysql` as the `RDBMS`.

I've followed the official documentation related to [Configuring APIM Analytics](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#step-4-configure-analytics), downloaded the `Connector/J 8.0.23` from [MySQL official website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and copied it to the `lib` directory, and here's my db-related configuration on `<APIM_ANALYTICS_HOME>/conf/worker/deployment.yaml` file:

```
  name: APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
  description: "The datasource used for APIM statistics aggregated data."
  jndiConfig:
    name: jdbc/APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
  definition:
    type: RDBMS
    configuration:
      jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/analytics_db?useSSL=false'
      username: behzad
      password: myStronPassword!
      driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      maxPoolSize: 50
      idleTimeout: 60000
      connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
      validationTimeout: 30000
      isAutoCommit: false
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot connect to JDBC URL jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/analytics_db?useSSL=false. Failed due to Failed to initialize pool: Unknown database 'analytics_db'
```

Here's the full log:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/behzad/0/projects/wso2/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0
RUNTIME_HOME environment variable is set to /home/behzad/0/projects/wso2/wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/wso2/worker
[2021-02-21 16:05:04,879]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.launcher.extensions.OSGiLibBundleDeployerUtils updateOSGiLib} - Successfully updated the OSGi bundle information of Carbon Runtime: worker  
osgi> [2021-02-21 16:05:07,208]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.websocket.WebSocketServerSC} - All required capabilities are available of WebSocket service component is available.
[2021-02-21 16:05:07,216]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.core.config.model.JmxReporterConfig} - Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
[2021-02-21 16:05:07,235]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.analytics.metrics.MetricsComponent} - Metrics Component is activated
[2021-02-21 16:05:07,241]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.internal.DataAgentDS} - Successfully deployed Agent Server 
[2021-02-21 16:05:07,902] ERROR {com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool} - HikariPool-4 - Exception during pool initialization. java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'analytics_db'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.rdbms.hikari.HikariRDBMSDataSource.getDataSource(HikariRDBMSDataSource.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.rdbms.hikari.HikariDataSourceReader.createDataSource(HikariDataSourceReader.java:74)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceBuilder.buildDataSourceObject(DataSourceBuilder.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceBuilder.buildDataSourceObject(DataSourceBuilder.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceBuilder.buildCarbonDataSource(DataSourceBuilder.java:44)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceManager.initDataSources(DataSourceManager.java:163)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.internal.DataSourceListenerComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(DataSourceListenerComponent.java:125)
    at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)

[2021-02-21 16:05:07,903] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.datasource.rdbms.hikari.HikariRDBMSDataSource} - Cannot connect to JDBC URL jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/analytics_db?useSSL=false. Failed due to Failed to initialize pool: Unknown database 'analytics_db'retrying in 5 seconds com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Unknown database 'analytics_db'
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:597)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:576)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.rdbms.hikari.HikariRDBMSDataSource.getDataSource(HikariRDBMSDataSource.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.rdbms.hikari.HikariDataSourceReader.createDataSource(HikariDataSourceReader.java:74)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceBuilder.buildDataSourceObject(DataSourceBuilder.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceBuilder.buildDataSourceObject(DataSourceBuilder.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceBuilder.buildCarbonDataSource(DataSourceBuilder.java:44)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceManager.initDataSources(DataSourceManager.java:163)
    at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.internal.DataSourceListenerComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(DataSourceListenerComponent.java:125)
    at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'analytics_db'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Did you create a database called analytics_db?

Comment: Oh, thank you, that solved the problem. I didn't know I should create the databases, they haven't mentioned it on the official documentation! I thought the scripts would create databases too.

Comment: I made it as the answer for the easiness of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **manually You need to create a database called analytics_db** and point to it. Then automatically DB tables will be created.